# Economically store images with similar background

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-codecs

We have a lot of images with similar background (can be represented as the camera on the street, make a 1 photo per minute). It is necessary to optimize their storage, ie, convert into something that will take up less space than the batch of jpeg images.
Our idea was to convert images to video (for example mpeg)/use any video codec, calculated that he was "find a common background" and greatly reduce the size of stored without loss of quality.
Are there any ready-made solutions for c# to achieve the goal? 
Googling have so far not resulted in.

Comment: show the code for your idea

Comment: You can use ffmpeg to convert bunch of images to video: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Comment: Unless you already have the knowledge to do this background recognition, isn't it easier to just compress the image? I've heard of a Dropbox algorithm that compresses 22% of a jpeg file losslessly.. you can try to make a C# (or managed C++) version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered the question. As a result, I decided to use ffmpeg, the most suitable codec was vp9 (pretty good x3 compress and acceptable x5).